# \b doesn't match when the preceding character is a word boundary

Tags: java, regex

I have a rather peculiar problem. I'm trying to find a pattern like `[some string][word boundary]`. Simplified, my code is:

```
final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(Pattern.quote(someString) + "\\b");
final String value = someString + " ";
System.out.println(pattern.matcher(value).find());
```

My logic tells me this should always output `true`, regardless of what `someString` is. However:

- if `someString` ends with a word character (e.g. "abc"), `true` is outputted;
- if `someString` ends with a word boundary (e.g. "abc."), `false` is outputted.

Any ideas what is happening? My current workaround is to use `\W` instead of `\b`, but I'm not sure of the implications.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A dot then a space is not a word boundary.

A word boundary is between a word character, then a non-word character, or visa versa.
ie between `[a-zA-Z0-9_][^a-zA-Z0-9_]` or `[^a-zA-Z0-9_][a-zA-Z0-9_]`

Answer (score 4):

A word boundary is a non-word character that is preceded by a word character or vice versa. The space preceded by a period (2 non-word characters) does not meet this requirement.

The effect of using `\W` is that any non-word characters will be matched (the same as `\b`, but without the condition that the character is preceded by a word character), which seems correct for your example.

Comment: Yes, but the period in `abc.` should become part of the regex (via `Pattern.quote("abc.")`. So the pattern should become "`abc.` followed by a word boundary", which should match `abc.` followed by a space.

Comment: @Felix for a character to be a word boundary it must be a non-word character that is preceded by a word character. A space preceded by a period does not meet this requirement.

Comment: Thanks! I was under the impression it was just a character class shortcut, like `\W`.